# MSVC 2017 - Bug - How to declare template member function of template class X as friend of nested class X::Y

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-c++, nested

I am trying to get a cmake C++ project that compiles and runs with GCC to compile with MSVC. I am using VS 2017.

I'm not the author of the code I'm just tasked with making it compile with MSVC.

The project is large so I am unsure how  can present a MCVE. However, I will try to explain as best as I can here:

I am getting this error:

Which correspinds to the `friend` declaration in the below `sibling_iterator` class.

However, `leftmost_output()` is a member of `node`.

The definition of `node` is appended below (see about 3/4 of the way down):

I'm pretty sure this is [related to the bug in VS related to nested template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978275/how-to-declare-template-member-function-of-template-class-x-as-friend-of-nested) as `sibling_iterator` and `node` are nested in a another template class.

My question is how could I make the whole node class a friend instead of specifying  a specific member function? This might work failing at any other suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Seems rather easy to produce an MVCE. Cut out the etraneous stuff from the classes above. Instantiate sibling_iterator in main.

Answer (score 1):

Smallest reproducible code is:

```
#include <map>
template <class T, class T2>
struct relative_iterator : T {};

struct edge : public std::map<int, int>::iterator {};
using T_edge = edge;

class node {
public:

    template <class T_iterable, class T_content>
    class sibling_iterator : public relative_iterator<T_iterable, T_content>
    {
    public:
        friend sibling_iterator<edge, T_edge>  node::leftmost_output();
    //..
    };

    static sibling_iterator<edge, T_edge> leftmost_output();  // <--move up
} ;
```

There are two ways to combat this:

#### Option 1

Move the definition of `leftmost_output()` above `class sibling_iterator`

#### Option 2

Make `node` a dependent name. If there is an alias to `name` which is dependent on `T_iterable`, then its lookup will be delayed to the time when `class sibling_iterator<T_iterable, T_contents>` is instantiated. The simplest way is to use standard utilities in the standard:

```
class sibling_iterator : public relative_iterator<T_iterable, T_content>
{
public:
    static constexpr bool dependent_true = std::is_same<T_iterable,T_iterable>::value;
    using dependent_node = typename std::enable_if<dependent_true, node>::type;
    friend sibling_iterator<edge, T_edge>  dependent_node::leftmost_output();
};
```

#### Option 2.5

But, if you prefer to define your own solution, you can define a `dependet_type<T, Dependent>` helper:

```
template <class T, class Dependent>
struct dependent_type
{
    using type = T;
};
template <class T, class Dependent>
using dependent_type_t = typename dependent_type<T, Dependent>::type;
```

And use it:

```
template <class T_iterable, class T_content>
class sibling_iterator : public relative_iterator<T_iterable, T_content>
{
public:
    using dependent_node = typename dependent_type<node, T_iterable>::type;
    friend sibling_iterator<edge, T_edge>  dependent_node::leftmost_output();
//..
};
```

I think that this is the best alternative, since it requires less changes to the existing code-base.

#### Option 2.5.5

I would have written a shorter variant:

```
friend sibling_iterator<edge, T_edge> dependent_type_t<node, T_iterable>::leftmost_output()
```

This looks perfect, since it requires minimal changes to the source code. I would have written it, had it not made the compiler crash:

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1469)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting this error:
>
> error C2039: 'leftmost_output': is not a member of 'mv::graph::node'
>
> [...]
>
> However, leftmost_output() is a member of node.
>
> The definition of node is appended below (see about 3/4 of the way
>   down):

Apparently, the VC compiler doesn't find the definition of `node`, as it refers to something in a different scope. Try moving the friend declarations below the definition of the nested `node` class.

Comment: @D Drmmr I didn't think of that, thank you, I will try.